# Why MongoRepository expose rest crud api and how to disable when using restController

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest

I have a spring application exposing rest api using a restController. It calls a layer service and then a layer Dao where i'm using MongoRepository to get crud stuffs.

```
public interface ProjectDao extends MongoRepository<Project, String> {
}

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/api/data")
public class DataController {
...
    @GetMapping(value = "projects/{id}")
    public Project findProjectById(@PathVariable String id) throws ResponseStatusException {
        Optional<Project> project = projectService.findById(id);

        if (project.isEmpty()) throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "product with id " + id + " does not exists");

        return project.get();
    }
...
}
```

I just configured swagger to generate the documentation and have discovered i can call directly all crud methods exposed from the mongorepository!!! But i do not want this behaviour as i want to expose only api from my rest controller.

I have my method GET /api/data/projects/{id} that call the findProjectById of my controller but i have also a method GET /projects/{id} which call directly the mongorepository. And all the other like delete, put, post which is really dangerous.

I'm using this dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I can't find how to configure that and why by default all rest api of mongorepository is exposed!

I someone know how to disable that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have found the solution only modifying maven dependencies.

I should use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Which publish rest service based on data model.